# OSGeo4W Shell set proxy

Tags: osgeo4w, proxy, shell

Where would I set a proxy server for OSGeo4W Shell? In OSGeo4Winstaller I use the IE Setting and in QGIS the "system default".

I can't establish connection to a WMS service. In my opinion there should be a place for this somewhere in `OSGeo4W\etc\ini` but I can't find anything on this subject.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. You can read about some alternative ways to set them for example from https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10.

When you have OSGeo4W window open you set proxy and proxy port for just that session simply with SET

```
SET http_proxy=my_proxy_server.com:8080
SET https_proxy=my_proxy_server.com:8080
```

Alternatively you can add those lines into OSGeo4W.bat file.